# Count the number of letters in the first word of a sentence

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I am in an introductory Java course at my university. For my assignment I have to write a program to display the number of 1 letter words in a sentence, 2 letter words in a sentence...etc. The sentence is user inputted. I am supposed to use a loop and I am not allowed to use arrays.

However for now just to start, I am just trying to find the number of letters in the first word of the sentence. What I have gives me either an incorrect letter count or an error saying that the String index is out of range.

```
  Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  int letters = 1; 

  int wordCount1 = 1; 

  System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
  String userInput = myScanner.nextLine();


  int space = userInput.indexOf(" "); // integer for a space character

  while (letters <= userInput.length()) {

    String firstWord = userInput.substring(0, space);
    if (firstWord.length() == 1)
      wordCount1 = 1;
    int nextSpace = space;
    userInput = userInput.substring(space);
  }
  System.out.print(wordCount1);
```

For example when I input "This is a sentence" it gives me "String index out of range: 4" Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now is a good time to learn also how to use a debugger. What is the value of variable "space"?

Comment: The value of `space` is never being updated

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
int len = userInput.split(" ")[0].length();
```

This will give you an array of words splitted by whitespace, then just get the first position in array and finally get the length.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I am not allowed to use arrays since we haven't covered them in class yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
userInput.indexOf(" ");
```

This gives you the length of the first word without the use of an array.

The StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown because, since `space` is never updated, the code ends up trying to *substring index 0 to 4 from a string with a length of 2*.

If `userInput` was printed in the while-loop, the output would be:

```
This is a sentence
 is a sentence
a sentence
ntence
ce
```

Then the StringIndexOutOfBounds is thrown.

The way I would count every word from the sentence without the use of an array would be:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
String input = in.nextLine();
in.close();

int wordCount = 0;

while (input.length() > 0) {
    wordCount++;
    int space = input.indexOf(" ");
    if (space == -1) { //Tests if there is no space left
        break;
    }
    input = input.substring(space + 1, input.length());
}

System.out.println("The number of word entered is: " + wordCount);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I understand the problem now, I just don't know how to fix it. I think the problem is with `userInput = userInput.substring(space);` which is supposed to make it go to the next word and the rest of the sentence but I have it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you haven't been updating space and letter.
See below your code with my little changes that should work fine.

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      int letters = 1; 

      int wordCount1 = 1;
      String firstWord = null;

      System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
      String userInput = myScanner.nextLine();


      int space = -2; //= userInput.indexOf(" "); // integer for a space character

      while (letters <= userInput.length() && space != -1) {

        space = userInput.indexOf(" ");
        if (space != -1) 
            firstWord = userInput.substring(0, space);
        if (firstWord.length() == 1)
          wordCount1 = 1;
        userInput = userInput.substring(space + 1);
      }
      System.out.print(wordCount1);
}
```